# replace a line that contains just a specific string using sed

Tags: replace, sed, line

Hi I have these tow lines in a text file:

```
debug "run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop"
run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop
```

I just want to replace the second line with e.g. SOME_TEXT. I use

```
sed -i '' -e's|run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop|SOME_TEXT|' /fu/bar
```

But both lines change. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Add `^` for beginning of line. This way it will just match lines *starting* with `run_rc_script...`:

```
sed -i '' -e's|^run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop|SOME_TEXT|' /fu/bar
```

#### Test

```
$ sed 's|^run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop|SOME_TEXT|' file
debug "run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop"
SOME_TEXT
```

#### Update

> You know, there's a little problem. These two lines begins with tab.
>   What should I do with that?

As [Kent suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443830/replace-a-line-that-contains-just-a-specific-string-using-sed/17443840?noredirect=1#comment25341678_17443840), use `^\s*`:

```
$ sed 's|^\s*run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop|SOME_TEXT|' file
        debug "run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop"
SOME_TEXT
```

#### Need to escape `$` on sed:

```
$ echo "hello$bye" | sed "s|hello$bye|adeu|g"
adeu
$ echo "hello$bye" | sed 's|hello$bye|adeu|g'
hello
```

Comment: +1 I learned something from the question and the answer. :) the `$` in sed. before I thought `$` should be always escaped if matching a literal `$`...

Comment: You know, there's a little problem. These two lines begins with tab. What should I do with that?

Comment: 2x thanks @Kent! I updated my answer with an example on escaping `$`. It is sometimes tricky and there is no a general rule, but it is possible not to escape it in certain cases.

Comment: @fedorqui quote is not the case. what I found is, in sed, if `$` is not the last char, it has special meaning (EOL). otherwise, sed will try to match `$` as literal dollar. e.g. `sed 's/a$/foo/' and sed 's/a$f/foo/'`. but I am not sure about it.  of course you are right for the quote stuff. double quote will expand variable, therefore `$` will be looked as the variable sign.

Comment: Interesting, I will keep an eye on this!

Answer (score 0):

Add a little `^` before the pattern to denote the start of line.

```
sed -e's|^run_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop|SOME_TEXT|' /fu/bar
```

EDIT:

If the lines begin with a TAB character, you can specify that in the pattern:

```
sed -e's|^\trun_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop|SOME_TEXT|' /fu/bar
```

In order to preserve the leading whitespace/tab, try:

```
sed -e's|^\([ \t]\+\)trun_rc_script $_rc_elem faststop|\1SOME_TEXT|' /fu/bar
```

Comment: You know, there's a little problem. These two lines begins with tab. What should I do with that?